# Timeout while receiving TCP packet using BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bytebuffer

I am using **BufferedReader** to read **TCP packets** on particular port in my **client code**. But my issue is **out of 5000 packets, 350 packets getting timeout** in 15 minutes time frame.I checked other answers in stackoverflow but my problem doesn't solve.

How i can overcome this **timeout issue** and why is it happening. Please help me resolve this issue. Below is my client code to read packets, program is in **JAVA**.

**Note: Packet length is 30.**

```
private void listen() throws Exception {
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = null;
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = null;  
        LocalDateTime now = null;
        int cnt=0;
        String data = null;
        String[] res = null;
            String[] res1 = null;
            String clientAddress="";
        while(true){
        Socket client = this.server.accept();
        clientAddress = "";
        clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream())); 
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 10240 );
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            try{
                dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                now=LocalDateTime.now(); 
            System.out.println("\r\n"+dtf.format(now)+":: " + clientAddress + ": " + data);

            }catch(Exception s){
                s.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think there's something wrong with your code? Maybe there's an issue at the network/logical level.

Comment: @g00se,  client putting more pressure on us to clear timeouts. i want to be sure that everything fine with program.

Comment: is there any other way i can read TCP packets using buffer que ?

Comment: I don't know anything about the content or logic of your app, but not closing the client stream could be a problem. Not so much a problem of coding but of logic.
Other observations:
a. Don't construct  that formatter inside the loop
b. You do nothing with that `ByteBuffer`

Comment: ok i will define formatter outside loop. ByteBuffer i added to check some other way later forgot to remove.

Comment: As a general rule you will experience fewer problems when you close sockets as soon as you can.